# Processing message queues quickly without wasting money on AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

What are some strategies and patterns for processing message queues quickly?

I have a Lambda function that is invoked on a schedule every x minutes to process a number of messages in the queue. I could reduce the interval, but a lot of the time there won’t be any messages to process and as Lambda is priced per request this would be cost inefficient. So I’m looking for a few ideas on other ways to achieve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An SQS queue can now be wired directly to a Lambda function as an event source, so you don't have to start the Lambda function on a schedule.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-adds-amazon-simple-queue-service-to-supported-event-sources/

Comment: Thanks Michael, this is perfect for me. I see this is a very recently added feature for AWS, so what would be the solution in the past for achieving this?

Comment: Implementing an SQS poller + Lambda invoker on EC2.